# How to limit the maximum value of a PositiveIntegerfield in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field stores percentage value in a model. How can I limit the possible values to 0-100 range in a more strict way than the model validators do<sup>1</sup>?

### Notes

1. [Model validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you're using ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run)

Comment: Is there a way you can use may be a validator at the form level, and make the necessary checks in the forms' `clean` method ?

Comment: Is there any 'max_length' type field option? 
p.s.- yeah, i know the answer with validator.

Comment: Not that i know of - However, you can write your custom model if you choose to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: Why not making a validation at the model level? again, implementing the ``clean`` method

Comment: You've checked out validators? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/validators/

Comment: yes phoebeB, i wanted to know if there is any django's inbuilt field validation.

Answer (score 10):

You should use a validator.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    percent_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(min_value=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(100),])
```

Personally, I would rather use a Float for storing a percentage, and use the 0-1 range. 
The validator should work in a similar fashion.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I created a custom field based on default fields. You should override __init__ and form_fields methods of default fields.